# Neo4j 3.0 setup issues

Tags: neo4j

With neo4j 2.3.x community edition I use to set the ip address to local host and change the port to allow multiple instances for development.

```
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7384
```

Upon starting the instance, I use to have a confirmation message with ip and port.

```
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [28531]... waiting for server to be ready........ OK.
http://localhost:7384/ is ready.
```

I would then upload data using a shell script and cypher commands.

```
$neo/bin/neo4j-shell -path $neo/data/graph.db -file upload.cypher
```

With neo4j 3.0, the server setup slightly changed. I turned on HTTP connection, CSV import, and shell connection.

```
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.address=localhost:7384

dbms.shell.enabled=true
# dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1
dbms.shell.port=1387
```

When I start the instance, I get the following message in which the port is not correct.

```
Starting Neo4j.
Started neo4j (pid 28718). By default, it is available at http://localhost:7474/
There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
```

Uploading data with the same shell script as for neo4j-2.3.x works well, no error message and I can see the data using neo4j-shell.

```
./neo4j-3.0.0/bin/neo4j-shell -path neo4j-3.0.0/data/graph.db
```

However, when I connect using host and port instead, I see no data. Furthermore, when I connect using the web interface, I see no data either.

```
./neo4j-3.0.0/bin/neo4j-shell -host localhost -port 1387
```

Is there anything wrong in my database setup?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.0 the location of the datastore has changed. 2.x used `data/graph.db`, in 3.0 it's by default in `data/databases/graph.db`. So you want to change your setup script to:

```
./neo4j-3.0.0/bin/neo4j-shell -path neo4j-3.0.0/data/databases/graph.db
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel stupide. Indeed, while loading I created a data/graph.db database.